# Maintainability in a class

Tags: oop

How to ensure maintainability in a class? Can it simply be done by creating class using design patterns or is there something else involved? Also, what are the characteristics of a good method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't do badly by following the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles.

SOLID is:

> SRP   Single responsibility principle
>   the notion that an object should have only a single responsibility.
>
> OCP
>   Open/closed principle
>   the notion that “software entities … should be open for extension, but closed for modification”.
>
> LSP
>   Liskov substitution principle
>   the notion that “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program”. See also design by contract.
>
> ISP
>   Interface segregation principle
>   the notion that “many client specific interfaces are better than one general purpose interface.”[5]
>
> DIP
>   Dependency inversion principle
>   the notion that one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”[5]
>   Dependency injection is one method of following this principle.

And DRY stands for Don't Repeat Yourself, meaning you should strive to remove any duplication in your code.

Comment: +1 Although I'd "replace" Liskov Substitution Principle with the Least SurPrise principle which includes it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put in a lot of effort to make sure you have a good interface. Once you have that, you can completely rewrite the class, if you want, without affecting any other code in the project. If your class is so big that you can't easily rewrite it, then that is an issue too.

Although Oded's answer is good for ensuring the maintainability of a program or library, this question is about *class* maintainability and for that, there are only two requirements... a good interface, and strong cohesion.